# map sum of square integers to a contiguous range of integers

Tags: number-theory, infinity, natural-numbers

Given a list $a$ of integers, $$n_{a_1}, n_{a_2}, ..., n_{a_d}$$ have $$N_a = \sum_{j=1}^d n_{a_j}^2.$$ The various $N_a$, $N_b$ etc. are integers, but are not contiguous: for example, if $d=2$, there's way to obtain $N=7$.

Are the $N$ for a fixed $d$ countably infinite? Does it hold for any $d$?

Comment: Are you asking whether the set $\{ N_{a} : \text{$a$ a list of integers} \}$, or perhaps $\{ N_{a} : \text{$a$ a list of integers of a fixed length $d$} \}$, is infinite?

Comment: @AndreasCaranti clarified

Comment: Well clearly the set of achievable $N$ for a fixed $d$ is countably infinite, because (1) it is countable, being a set of integers, and (2) it is infinite, because corresponding to the lists $(1, 1, \dots), (2, 2, \dots), (3, 3,\dots)$, we get sums $(d, 2^2d, 3^2d, \dots)$ which are all distinct. Does this answer your question or is it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, for any fixed $d$, you are considering the set $S_d$ of all integers that can be expressed as a sum of $d$ squares (of integers).

- For $d = 2$, there is [Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares) which leads to the consequence that ([see here](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Integer_as_Sum_of_Two_Squares)) any integer $n$ can be expressed as the sum of two squares if and only if every prime divisor of the form $4k+3$ occurs to an even power.
- For $d = 3$, there is [a theorem which states that](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Integer_as_Sum_of_Three_Squares) a number $n$ can be expressed as the sum of three squares if and only if it is not of the form $4^k \left({8 m + 7}\right)$ for some $k$ and $m$.
- For $d \ge 4$, there is [Lagrange's four-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem) which says that *any* integer can be expressed as a sum of $d$ squares.

In all cases (for all $d$), the set of $N$ that can be expressed as a sum of $d$ squares is a countably infinite subset of $\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$ (the nonnegative integers), and is in fact identical to $\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$ if $d \ge 4$.